# Socket.io online users list doesn't work properly in production

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a online users page using Socket.io in a exprses web server. The code I'm using is listed below. When I'm using the website in the local network it works fine. But in production Socket.io behaves in a inexplicable way

**app.js**

```
...

const app = express()

const http = require('http').createServer(app)

const io = require('socket.io')(http)

let activeUsers = []

...

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  let userName

  socket.on('user viewing', function(user){
    let inActiveUsers = false

    for(var x = 0; x < activeUsers.length; x++) {
        if(activeUsers[x].username == user) {
            inActiveUsers = true
            activeUsers[x].last_activity = MDate.getDateTime()
            break
        }
    }

    if(!inActiveUsers) {
        activeUsers.push({"username": user, "last_activity": MDate.getDateTime()})
    }

    userName = user

    io.emit('active users', activeUsers)

  })

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){

    let userIndex = -1

    for(var x = 0; x < activeUsers.length; x++) {
        if(activeUsers[x].username == userName) {
            userIndex = x
            break
        }
    }

    if(userIndex != -1) {
      activeUsers[x].last_activity = 'NULL'
    }

    io.emit('active users', activeUsers)
  })

})

...
```

In every other page I have implemented the following client side JavaScript code

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
  socket.emit('user viewing', '<%= user.username %>');
</script>
```

activeUsers.ejs

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
          var socket = io();
          socket.on('active users', function(activeUsers){

            document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = '';

            for(var x = 0; x < activeUsers.length; x++) {
              if(activeUsers[x].last_activity != 'NULL') {
                  $('#users').append('<tr><td>' + activeUsers[x].username + '</td><td>' + activeUsers[x].last_activity + '</td></tr>');
              }
            }
          });
        </script>
```

When I am on localhost the site shows all active users properly. But when I'm using the site in production. The site shows only few users who are online even though others are online too. Sometimes it doesn't even show the account that is viewing the page. I'm using PM2 for production. What could be the issue for this?

Comment: Are you using cluster mode in PM2 ? If yes, your node instances doesn't share the same memory and because you are saving `activeUsers` in a variable that only the running process have access to it, every instance have it's own `activeUsers` array. you need to move your active users array to something like reddis, and let every instance of node read from it.

Comment: @AsafAviv I'm not using PM2 on cluster mode. I'm running a single process. Therefore the activeUsers has only one instance in memory